# Can't get property from valid stdClass object

Tags: php, json, stdclass

I'm having a very interesting problem with PHP. The following code grabs a line from a text file, decodes that text as json into an stdClass object, then puts it into an array conditionally on one of its properties.

```
$fileStream = @fopen($fileName, 'r+');
    $lastUpdate = $_POST['lastUpdate'];
    if($fileStream) {
        $eventArray = array();
        while (($buffer = fgets($fileStream, 8192)) !== false) {
                $decodedEvent = json_decode($buffer);
                echo var_dump($decodedEvent);
            if ($decodedEvent->timestamp > $lastUpdate) {
                array_push($eventArray, $decodedEvent);
            }
        }
        $jsonEvents = json_encode($eventArray);
        echo $jsonEvents;
    }
    else {
        $fileStream = @fopen($fileName, 'a');
    }
    @fclose($fileStream);
```

This produces the error:

```
Notice:Trying to get property of non-object in C:\****\gameManager.php on line 23
```

I know that the object is valid in multiple ways. For instance, var_dump is producing this:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
 ["name"]=>
 string(4) "move"
 ["args"]=>
 array(3) {
   [0]=>
   int(24)
   [1]=>
   int(300)
   [2]=>
   int(50)
 }
 ["timestamp"]=>
 float(1352223678463)
}
```

If I try to access $decodedEvent using `$decodedEvent["timestamp"]` I get an error telling me that objects can't be accessed as arrays.

Also, it does indeed echo proper json, which can only be encoded from a proper object:

```
[{"name":"move","args":[24,300,50],"timestamp":1352223678463}]
```

Am I missing something here, or is PHP misbehaving? Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: Here is the input from the file:

```
{"name":"move","args":[24,300,50],"timestamp":1352223678463}
```

Comment: Your error (*objects can't be accessed as arrays.*) and the PHP contradict, which is it? Also, which is line 23?

Comment: Ah, that was an error on my part. Edited to reflect access as an array.
`if ($decodedEvent->timestamp > $lastUpdate) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON format is *incorrect*. That's not to say *invalid*. But given this format the root element is an array of `stdClass`.

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  class stdClass#1 (3) {
     // ...
```

If this is a truly a single object, I would resolve this at the source with the following, proper JSON:

```
{"name":"move","args":[24,300,50],"timestamp":1352223678463}
```

If that is not possible, you need to access it in PHP with proper array notation:

```
echo $decodedEvent[0]->timestamp;
```

#### UPDATE

The updated JSON you provided appears valid and correctly formatted given your code. My guess is a line in the file does not contain valid JSON (e.g. empty line) and as such `json_decode()` is *failing* which results in the PHP Notice.

I encourage you to test for this in your loop:

```
if ($decodedEvent && $decodedEvent->timestamp > $lastUpdate)
```

Also bear in mind this is a *notice*. And while I advocate clean code, it is not an *error* strictly speaking.

Comment: Yes. But it is incorrectly formatted based on the code. Therefore either JSON or PHP code needs to be updated.

Comment: You are judging by the output of his json_encode on the array the code is making. The source of the input file is not shown, but it does not sound like it is a JSON array, but rather single lines of JSON objects.

Comment: @jimp, that is a good point. I am working from what was provided. The OP should update the question with the input to be sure.

Comment: {"name":"move","args":[24,300,50],"timestamp":1352223678463}
^Above is the input, also updating the question.

Comment: That works fine for me. Are you positive that is what's being *read* by PHP.

Comment: Those are the exact contents of $buffer, just before decoding.

Comment: The error in the OP is the exact error, just with the exact path obfuscated.
The lines before and after of what?

Comment: That did it, there was indeed whitespace at EOF. So frustrating that it didn't audibly fail.

Comment: Why would it? You never checked for failure :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this Function to Convert stdClass Objects to Multidimensional Arrays

```
    function objectToArray($d) {
        if (is_object($d)) {
            // Gets the properties of the given object
            // with get_object_vars function
            $d = get_object_vars($d);
        }

        if (is_array($d)) {
            /*
            * Return array converted to object
            * Using __FUNCTION__ (Magic constant)
            * for recursive call
            */
            return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $d);
        }
        else {
            // Return array
            return $d;
        }
    }
```

[Sources](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/php-tip-convert-stdclass-object-to-multidimensional-array-and-convert-multidimensional-array-to-stdclass-object/)

Comment: You can have json_decode return an array, set true as the second argument. I'd like to know why the above isn't working.